# Should/Can I make changes to data on nested resolvers?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Say I have a `MemberType` like this

```
import {
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString
} from 'graphql'
import readPhoneNumbersByMemberId from '../resolvers/readPhoneNumbersByMemberId'
import PhoneNumberType from './PhoneNumberType'

const MemberType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Member',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    firstName: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    lastName: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    phoneNumbers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PhoneNumberType),
      resolve: readPhoneNumbersByMemberId
    }
  }
})

export default MemberType
```

and a `PhoneNumberType` like this

```
import {
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString
} from 'graphql'

const PhoneNumberType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'PhoneNumber',
  fields: {
    value: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    }
  }
})

export default PhoneNumberType
```

and a `QueryType` like this

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    readMembers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(MemberType),
      resolve: readMembers
    }
  }
})
```

Now, if I query a GraphQL schema to retrieve a member, the resolve functions `readMembers` and `readPhoneNumbersByMemberId` will be invoked to fetch data from a source.

Is it possible to use the same mechanism on mutations?

Comment: You mean using the same resolver logic as the resolver for the mutation?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to take advantage of the same "resolver cascade" to run create/update statements?

Comment: Do I have to perform all create/update statements on the root resolver, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but **you should not**. field resolvers are really made to fetch data. Putting create/update/delete logic inside of nested resolvers could quickly become problematic and introduce the same problems you would like to solve with graphql.

It is so much discouraged to the point that facebook created a whole special type called `input` for any composite objects that's sent as arguments to mutations (or query).

If you can explain the benefits of splitting the mutation logic, it might be a good RFC for GraphQL spec to accept mutate function for every field, this way you will keep the mutation logic separate while achieving the same nested nature.

If you still like to try that, you can just return an `action` field on the returned object from the root resolver and make the changes you want on the nested resolvers only if you see that field. Make sure you return the data that was changed on the nested resolver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know readPhoneNumbersByMemberId would retrieve phone numbers after mutation but I'd like to know if I can use a mutatePhoneNumbersByMemberId to let a nested type taking care of create/update ops.

Comment: I tried but it seems like I have to implement all the create/update logic in the root resolver.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You can make it work possibly with action flags that will be propagated to your `phoneNumbersByMemberId` but that is discouraged. You should create the mutation logic on the root resolver and let the nested type resolvers take care of data retrieval only. If you can change your question to be "Should/Can I make changes to data on nested resolvers?" I will answer that so it will be kept for future dev's asking the same thing.

Comment: Thanks again. Title changed.